# Filter same tag images and save another folder at google drive using google colaboratory

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have downloaded dataset and it includes images of flood, fire, volcano and etc. Above those I want to filter flood tag images and save them in another folder. My all images include a folder in a google drive. How to do it?

Dataset Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lGD1LSnPnyoCOLfPXiZ_Y4zWgyh93ltn?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the dataset format? I mean, how to distinguish between flood images and fire images. Can you post a link to the dataset?

Comment: @Pavindu I Have added the link in the question

Comment: Better to put what you have tried out. Follow guildlines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset you posted has 6 types of natural disasters, `hurricane`, `volcano`, `earthquake`, `flooding`, `tsunami`, and `wildfire`. Each image file name contains one of these words, so you can easily filter images that are relevant to floods.

```py
from google.colab import drive 
import os

i_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/images"
flood_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/flood_images"

drive.mount('/content/drive')
os.chdir(i_path)  

for file_name in os.listdir():
  file_path = f"{i_path}/{file_name}"
  if "flooding" in file_name:
    s_p = os.path.join(i_path, file_path)
    d_p = os.path.join(flood_dir)
    !mv "$s_p" "$d_p"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the images are already labeled, better to use these labels to categorize the images. Inside the `labels` folder, there are JSON files containing image label data.
You can fetch image names and relevant disaster types from JSON files.

```
"metadata": {
    "sensor": "GEOEYE01",
    "provider_asset_type": "GEOEYE01",
    "gsd": 2.0916247,
    "capture_date": "2018-09-20T16:04:41.000Z",
    "off_nadir_angle": 28.017313,
    "pan_resolution": 0.52282465,
    "sun_azimuth": 153.94543,
    "sun_elevation": 53.722378,
    "target_azimuth": 190.82309,
    "disaster": "hurricane-florence",
    "disaster_type": "flooding",
    "catalog_id": "1050010012411600",
    "original_width": 1024,
    "original_height": 1024,
    "width": 1024,
    "height": 1024,
    "id": "MjU0Njk0MQ.clApx1C8IcFymibsGi1JLu1eKhU",
    "img_name": "hurricane-florence_00000324_post_disaster.png"
  }
```

You can use the following code piece. It's written to copy an image to its relevant category folder (Ex: image with disaster_type 'fire' -> /categorized/fire/). Ultimately all the images will be categorized into separate folders.

```
from google.colab import drive 
import os 
import json 
import shutil

drive.mount('/content/drive')
# change paths according to yours
main_folder_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Backup/train"
images_folder_path = main_folder_path+"/images"
labels_folder_path = main_folder_path+"/labels"
categorized_folder_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/Backup/categorized"

os.chdir(main_folder_path)
for json_filename in os.listdir(labels_folder_path):
  json_path = os.path.join(main_folder_path, "labels", json_filename)
  f = open(json_path, 'r')
  data = json.load(f)
  disaster_type = data["metadata"]["disaster_type"]
  img_name = data["metadata"]["img_name"]
  print("disaster:", disaster_type, "image:", img_name)
  f.close()
  img_filepath = os.path.join(main_folder_path, "images", img_name)
  category_folderpath = os.path.join(categorized_folder_path, disaster_type)
  if os.path.exists(img_filepath):
    if not os.path.exists(category_folderpath):
      os.mkdir(category_folderpath)
    shutil.copy(img_filepath, category_folderpath)
```